# Time reversal symmetry in Bilayer Graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, time-reversal-symmetry, graphene

In general the time reversal symmetry operation for spin half angular momentum requires $$H(-p)=\sigma_{y}H^{*}(p)\sigma_{y}.$$ The Hamiltonian of a bilayer Graphene is $$H(p)=\frac{1}{2m}(p^{2}_{x}-p^{2}_{y})\sigma_{x}+\frac{p_{x}p_{y}+p_{y}p_{x}}{2m}\sigma_{y}.$$ This should satisfy the time reversal operation $$H(-p)=\sigma_{y}H^{*}(p)\sigma_{y}.$$ However this satisfies $$H(-p)=-\sigma_{y}H^{*}(p)\sigma_{y}.$$ What am I missing here? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think an overall negative sign does not split energy spectrum. Thats why the Hamiltonian is still time invariant for Bi layer Graphene. A complete relation for time in variance should employ $H(-p)=\pm(\sigma_{y}H^{*}(p)\sigma_{y})$.

Comment: How do you obtain this formula for the bilayer?

Comment: @ IcyOtter, this is the link. Is anything wrong? https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsta.2007.2156

Comment: Well, in the tight-binding graphene Hamiltonian, the mass does not show up. Second, graphene has two valleys which are related by time reversal. This means that switching the sign of $p$ takes the Hamiltonian to the other valley